# How to run the Insert/Update OLEDB command based on a conditional split that checks Rowcount == 0 in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

The DFT source someday returns no result.So have to insert/update the table based on some default value which is defined in the derived column. As you can see in the attached figure i am using conditional split and checking the Rowcount == 0 if this condition satisfy this will  process the OLEDB command where i am using a simple Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Invalid]
           (Code]
           ,[Date]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           ,[UpdatedDate])
     VALUES
           (?
           ,?
           ,GETDATE()
           ,GETDATE())
```

The code and the date value is defined in the derived column and mapped in the OLEDB command column mappings.

the data flow task looks like this

[image]

When the Oledb source rowcount > 0 then the value is inserting in the OLEDB destination.
but when rowcount = 0 the value is not inserting through OLEDB command. The dataflow task is not returning any error. When i debug the rowcount variable it showing its value as 0 but still it is not doing the insert.

Please let me know how to solve this.

I don't want to use MERGE JOIN/Lookup for this as it is always insert/update single row.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, if row count = 0 then it will not process any command since no rows are found in the pipeline, which will not execute the OLE DB Command. I think you are looking for an Execute SQL Task.

You should remove the conditional split and the OLE DB Command. And outside the data flow task, add an Execute SQL Task after the data flow task and set an expression in the precedence constraint (if Row count = 0) that links the Data flow task and the Execute SQL task.

For additional information about precedence constraint you can refer to the following article:

- [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/working-with-precedence-constraints-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: The source query contain function which connects to Azure DB. So i don't want to execute the function twice once for getting the ROWCOUNT and another for getting the data. Is there any way to get the rowcount assigned to 0 value in DFT if no rows returned from the OLEDB source.

Comment: @SQL006 I don't think that

Comment: i removed the Row count = 0 from the DFT and checked the rowcount =0 once the DFT processed and execute the insert in execute sql task. avoiding the azure query call twice now in one execution i have to check the rowcount. I have to initialise the rowcount variable to zero at the start of the package.